# Selenium argument[0].scroll.to function is not working a second time

Tags: java, python, selenium

I'm using python for selenium but I need to scroll using the javascript function. It works right here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from secrets import pw
from secrets import email
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   scroll_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div')
                last_ht, ht = 0, 1
                while last_ht != ht:
                    last_ht = ht
                    sleep(1)
                    ht = self.driver.execute_script("""
                        arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight); 
                        return arguments[0].scrollHeight;
                        """, scroll_box)
```

For some reason this one:

```
scroll_box2 = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('main-view-container__scroll-node')
        last_ht, ht = 0, 1
        while last_ht != ht:
            last_ht = ht
            sleep(1)
            ht = self.driver.execute_script("""
                arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight); 
                return arguments[0].scrollHeight;
                """, scroll_box2)
```

Give's this error:

```
Message: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollTo is not a function
```

WHY? I need to scroll again but its not working. I don't know java well so i copy these from others. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need to see more code let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use this:

```
ht = self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: ok so i think this will work as i get no error but i need it to scroll scroll_box2 not window

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you might want `.scrollIntoView()`.

```
ht = self.driver.execute_script("""
                arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
                """, scroll_box2)
```

Comment: It gave the same error... i wonder if i dont have everything i need imported here.. this is what i have    from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from secrets import pw
from secrets import email
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function